# Linux project: bash script to archive and remove files

Tags: linux, bash, file, cron, tar

I've been set a mini project to run a bash script to archive and remove files that are older than 'x' number of days. The file will be archived in the /nfs/archive directory and they need to be compressed (TAR) or removed... e.g. '/test.sh 15' would remove files older than 15 days. Moreover, I also need to input some validation checking before removing files...

My code so far:

```
> #!/bin/bash 
> 
> #ProjectEssentials:
> 
> # TAR: allows you to back up files
> # cronjob: schedule taks 
> # command: find . -mtime +('x') -exec rm {} \; this will remove files older than 'x' number of days 
> 
> find /Users/alimohamed/downloads/nfs/CAMERA -type f -name '*.mov'
> -mtime +10 -exec mv {} /Users/limohamed/downloads/nfs/archive/ \;
> 
> # TAR: This will allow for the compression
> 
> tar -cvzf doc.tar.gz /Users/alimohamed/downloads/nfs/archive/
> 
> # Backup before removing files 'cp filename{,.bak}'?  find /Users/alimohamed/downloads/nfs/CAMERA -type f name '*.mov' -mtime +30
> -exec rm {} \; ~
```

Any help would much appreciated!!

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: The question is how to produce a script which performs the aforementioned task... Is my code correct? Am I on the right lines? Any suggestions? Thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: Please reformat your code. No need to have '>' on every line. Make it hard to test

Comment: Do you want to compress the file AND remove them ?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified script to fix few typos. Note backup file will have a YYYY-MM-DD, to allow for multiple backups (limited to one backup per day).Using TOP to make script generic - work on any account.

```
X=15      # Number of days

          # Move old files (>=X days) to archive, via work folder
TOP=~/downloads/nfs
mkdir -p "$TOP/work"
find $TOP/CAMERA -type f -name '*.mov' -mtime +"$X" -exec mv {} "$WORK/work" \;

       # Create daily backup (note YYYY-MM-DD in file name from work folder
tar -cvzf $TOP/archive/doc.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -C "$TOP/work" .

       # Remove all files that were backed-up, If needed
find "$TOP/work" -type f -name '*.mov' -exec rm {} \; ~
```

Comment: Thanks, @dash-o, really appreciate it! So just to confirm the 'TOP' command makes the script generic? And I will have to use it when writing the above script or can it be changed?

Comment: @AliMohamed The TOP simplifies the script. It will also adjust the script to use the RUNNING user home folder, instead of  '/Users/alimohamed' only. As a side note, remember the SO users do not have '/users/alimohamed', it will be easier to test/comment on a script which can run on every users account.

Comment: got an unexpected error...

line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hk.sh: line 11: `tar -cvzf $TOP/archive/doc.($date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -C "$TOP/work" .'

Comment: @DAMO, The date base file name generation was fixed. Typo, Sorry

Comment: apologies, didn't quite get that, are you referring to the bracket?

Comment: In the TAR command, the date command was started with '($date ...)', fixed to '$(date ...)

Comment: a .
find: /Users/alimohamed: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @DAMO - please run with '-x' to some some understanding of where the problem is. You should be able to correct it by youself.